# PHP run query in same function multiple times with random numbers

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm creating a website where on the frontpage I want to place 5 random women and 5 random men. I am stuck at the moment.

My question is how should I proceed: any better suggestions, or any way I can do this better?

Currently what I'm thinking about is running "count" different queries storing every single one of them in an array as the query succeeds and then output username, picture and more on the frontpage.

```
public function load_member_suggestions($items = array()) {
    $count  = $items['count'];
    $gender = $items['gender'];
    $age = rand(16, 60);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE age = {$age} AND gender = {$gender}";
    $output = array(
    );
    if(count($output) === $count) {
        echo 'works';
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the `for()` or `foreach()` loop function: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php / http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Two questions: 1. you want to select only one person per query or five? 2. If you want to select 5 persons at once, shall they be with different gender or not? P.S. What is the datatype of `gender` column?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE age BETWEEN (16 AND 60) AND gender = {$gender} ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
```

Try this one